# how to use color picker for changing text intead of background

Tags: javascript, jquery

the function of color picker is not getting into desired field

```
    <input class="jscolor {onFineChange:'update(this)'}" value="choose color">
    <iframe  name="richTextField" id="richTextField" style="border:#000000 1px solid; width:700px; height:300px;">
<script type="javascript" src="js/jscolor.js"></script>

<script>
function update(jscolor) {

// 'jscolor' instance can be used as a string
document.getElementById('richTextField').style.backgroundColor = '#' + jscolor

}
  </script>
```

i want that when a user clicks on the text field the color picker will open user select his desire color and then the text written in the iframe should be of that color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fixed this for you.This example demonstrates changing background. To change text color, you can define iframe source and replace "`y.body.style.backgroundColor = '#' + jscolor;`" with "`y.body.style.color = '#' + jscolor;`" .Here's the snippet code:

```
<script src="http://jscolor.com/release/2.0/jscolor-2.0.4/jscolor.js"></script>    

<input class="jscolor {onFineChange:'update(this)'}" value="choose color">

 <iframe id="richTextField" height="200" width="600"></iframe>

<script>
function update(jscolor) {
    var x = document.getElementById("richTextField");
    var y = (x.contentWindow || x.contentDocument);
    if (y.document)y = y.document;
    y.body.style.backgroundColor = '#' + jscolor;
}
</script>
```

[View Snippet](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EKGKRd)

Comment: the function is not calling in the ifrma the color picker is not open

Comment: Can you be a bit clear about iframe? Do you want text color to change in a separate iframe or the same window?

Comment: the input field is the color picker box when i click on it it should open but it is not opening and second after the color picking the below iframe is the text field like after color picking text i write in that iframe should be of color choosen

Comment: r u there Arun Sharma

Comment: bro u have done well but i want to chanage the color of text or paragraph that text which which i will write in the iframe box

Comment: in this the background color is changing

Comment: Right. You can define iframe src and replace " y.body.style.backgroundColor = '#' + jscolor;" with  "y.body.style.color = '#' + jscolor;"

Comment: the text is still written or chowing in black color

Comment: done thank u soooooo muuuuccccchhhh bro great work love it

Comment: and second it is possible that like when i write hello in the iframe by choosing black color and then i write hi in the same iframe by choosing white color the hello should be in black color the white will not effect it

Comment: Yeah! you can assign different classes and update class color accordingly.

Comment: Please follow this to mark correct answer : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: sir but can u do this for me choosing different color